# Custom Authorization using signalr PersistentConnection with websockets transport

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, authorization, signalr

I im trying to authorize a user for some connections in SignalR, my issue is that using WebSockets as the transport i cannot set HttpContext.Current.User without getting an exception. The authorization object also needs to be accessible from the controller and
there also the authentication is custom throughout the web-api portion with an IFilter implementaion.

I must be missing something here, before we upgraded to a 2012 server that supports websockets
we simply used HttpContext.Current.User and everything worked fine, Looking at alternatives
through SignalR, there is an implementation for [AuthorizeAttribute] but only for Hubs (and im not sure that changing HttpContext.Current.User there will not throw an exception as well when working with websockets).

Thanks in advance,
  Totem.

Comment: Where are you trying to access HttpContext.Current.User? Are you using a PersistentConnection?

Comment: Yes im using PersistentConnection. and im trying to access it inside the OnConnected or AuthorizeRequest overloads. which works fine unless the transport is websockets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out the i was doing things too late in the pipeline, instead of checking the headers while OnConnected or OnAuthorizeRequest in order to verify the user and set HttpContext.Current.User, in case of WebSockets it was too late in the set the HttpContext.Current.User, and since it wasn't set by my custom MessageHandler the User object inside the IRequest was a default empty one.

Had to write an IHttpModule and authorize all uri's that resolve into a PersistantConnection and then set HttpContext.Current.User, then the User object in IRequest is propagated correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Inside of PersistentConnection.AuthorizeRequest and PersistentConnection.OnConnected, you should access the User property of the IRequest object that is passed in as a parameter instead of the static HttpContext.Current.User property. This should work for all transports.

Comment: Doesn't work, the User object inside the IRequest hasnt been propagated by anything therefore it doesn't contain the custom Object i use for authentication, Also there is only a setter for the User attribute which means i can't set it when AuthorizeRequest or OnConnected are called. also if i could to simplefy things i would like to share the  User object in this context.